# ruby gem qtbindings' emit makes app freeze

Tags: ruby, qt, signals, freeze, emit

**My app freezes when I use emit to update status on GUI.**

I want to know the reason or how to avoid this freeze. Thanks for your review.

**My test environment**

- Windows 7 x64
- railsinstaller-3.0.0.exe(MD5 : 26889DE0029C01A45AD2AED873708057)

  - https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/releases/download/3.0.0-alpha.2/railsinstaller-3.0.0.exe
- qtbindings (4.8.5.2 x86-mingw32)
- qtbindings-qt (4.8.5 x86-mingw32)

**The demo app is present below.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: UTF-8
#

require 'Qt'

class App < Qt::MainWindow
    signals 'test()'
    slots   'on_test()'

    def initialize
        super

        @label = Qt::Label.new
        self.centralWidget = @label

        self.show

        connect self, SIGNAL('test()'), SLOT('on_test()')
        start_count
    end

    def start_count
        Thread.new do
            loop {
                emit test()
            }
        end
    end

    def on_test()
        @label.text = @label.text.to_i + 1
    end
end

app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
App.new
app.exec
```

@hyde
Thank you for you answer.

Solution 2 of qtbindings seems to be no help.

```
connect self, SIGNAL('test()'), SLOT('on_test()')
=> 
connect self, SIGNAL('test()'), SLOT('on_test()'), Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection
```

Solution 1 was tested and the app runs fluently.

**The code of Solution 1:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: UTF-8
#

require 'Qt'

class App < Qt::MainWindow
    slots   'on_test()'

    def initialize
        super

        @label = Qt::Label.new
        self.centralWidget = @label

        self.show

        @c = Qt::AtomicInt.new

        start_count
        start_timer
    end

    def start_count
        Thread.new do
            loop {
                @c.fetchAndAddRelaxed(1)
            }
        end
    end

    def start_timer
        t = Qt::Timer.new(self)
        t.start(16)
        connect t, SIGNAL('timeout()'), SLOT('on_test()')
    end

    def on_test()
        @label.text = @c.fetchAndAddRelaxed(0) + 1
    end
end

app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
App.new
app.exec
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Try adding a sleep to your thread loop, and see if it helps.

Comment: Also, without sleeping, try printing count of emitted signals, and count of `on_test` calls. I suspect emit count will grow faster than `on_test` count, meaning the signal queue size keeps growing.

Comment: @hyde: 
It is true that emit count grows faster than on_test count without sleep. But event with sleep of 0, 0.01 or 0.001 secconds, the app freezes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speculation on reason: the Qt main thread event loop never gets to process application events, because it is too busy delivering queued signals. The signals are queued, because they are between threads, so slot gets called in the right thread, independent of the emitting thread (and they *must* be queued in this case, because slot manipulates GUI objects, which is only allowed from the main thread)

---

There are a few alternatives to solve this. I don't really know Ruby, or its Qt bindings, so here's just a rough outline:

### Solution 1: let the thread loop go around as fast as it can:

1. Create an atomic variable. Either use some Ruby type, or [`QAtomicInt`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qatomicint.html) (I assume that's possible with the Ruby Qt bindings).
2. In your thread loop, just increment the atomic variable, instead of emitting a signal.
3. Add a `QTimer` for updating the `@label.text` at desired intervals. If the user is supposed to be able to read the number, I'd suggest something like 500 ms interval. Minimum sensible interval is something like 16 ms for ~60 fps update rate.
4. Connect the timer timeout to `on_test` and get the value of the atomic integer to update the text.

That way updating of the numeric value is independent of displaying it.

### Solution 2: make the thread block until emitted signal is actually delivered:

Use connection type [BlockingQueuedConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) (note: do not use with single thread). Add that connection type to the signal connection statement (however you do it with Ruby Qt). Then the emitting thread will block until the target slot is actually called, so the signals will only be emitted at the rate they can be processed, no faster.

Comment: I cannot make the source formmated in comment. So I posted the solution 2 source in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Your application freezes cause you emit signals in the infinite loop but not cause of emit

Comment: It is strange that without sleep the app freezes immediately. So I don't think that the freeze has direct relation to the infinite loop.

start_count can be written like this. The app still freezes.
    
    def start_count
        Thread.new do
            10000.times {
                emit test()
            }
        end
    end